# Order By in Hibernate Native Query

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to build a parameterized order by and sort by native query using this code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e.first_name as firstName, e.last_name as lastName, jh.start_date as startDate, jh.end_date as endDate, " +
        "j.job_title as jobName, d.department_name as departmentName FROM JOB_HISTORY jh " +
        "JOIN JOBS j ON jh.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID " +
        "JOIN DEPARTMENTS d ON JH.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID " +
        "JOIN EMPLOYEES e ON jh.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID " +
        "ORDER BY :sortBy :orderBy", nativeQuery = true)
List<EmployeeJobView> getAllEmployeeJob(String sortBy, String orderBy);
```

Which gives me an exception and isn't the correct way to do an Order By HQL.

Here is the projection interface

```
public interface EmployeeJobView {

    @Value("#{target.firstName + ' ' + target.lastName}")
    String getFullName();
    
    Timestamp getStartDate();
    Timestamp getEndDate();
    String getJobName();
    String getDepartmentName();
}
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(...
"ORDER BY :sortBy :orderBy", nativeQuery = true)
List<EmployeeJobView> getAllEmployeeJob(@Param("sortBy") String sortBy, @Param("orderBy") String orderBy);
```

You have to specify @Param name when using named parameters. You can also use unnamed parameters like:

```
@Query(...
"ORDER BY ?1 ?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<EmployeeJobView> getAllEmployeeJob(String sortBy, String orderBy);
```